# How to piece together short reads of DNA? Matching base pairs in file of sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, matching, short

I am trying to piece together DNA short reads. I need to match around 3 base pairs to other short read fragments. (base pair= ex. TCG (basically just 3 letters))

I have tried regex expressions but when I try to read a file with a bunch of short reads I need to make nucleotides a variables and I don't think regex does that. I have a file with a bunch of these short reads and i need to match these base pairs to other short reads that have these same base pair sequences.

ex. I have these two lines of short reads in a file:

AAAGGGTTTCCCGGGAAA*TCA*

CCCGGGAAA*TCA*GGGAAATTT

I need the outcome to be:

AAAGGGTTTCCCGGGAAA*TCA*GGGAAATTT

How do I match and paste the matched lines on top of the other lines to where I can combine them at the point of similarity?

Comment: around 5 is how much?

Comment: Hi Alpa,
Your description is very short, and you haven't told us what you've tried. It's difficult to even tell what you're trying to do.

The best I can tell, is that you're trying to align your short-reads to form longer reads. This is not something I suggest you manually do, and is an ongoing field of research for the best way to do it. I suggest you look at the tools available in the community to accomplish the task.

Comment: assuming you are really dealing with DNA data, there are lots of very specialist tools for doing this (and allowing for mis-reads).  try https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ or searching for "sequence assembly"

Answer (score 0):

You can just find the index of the match sequence in the second sequence and concatenate them:

```
seq1 = 'AAAGGGTTTCCCGGGAAATCA'
seq2 = 'CCCGGGAAATCAGGGAAATTT'
match_pair_count = 5
match_seq = seq1[-match_pair_count:]
match_index = seq2.rfind(match_seq)
combined_seq = seq1[:-match_pair_count] + seq2[match_index:]
```

NOTE: If you need to catch cases where the match sequence doesn't appear in the second sequence you will need to add code to handle `match_index == -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward solution for each subsequence compute 5 tail and five head. Try then all the combination with deapth first search.

More sophisticated way to draw a graph where directed edges are labeled with number of coinsiding letters (within say 4-9). Apply traveling salesman solutions or other appropriate algo to find shortest path throw all vertices.

I am sure there is a lot of appropriate tools and techniques tailored for genome inference. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGxx7TvQ3f4.

To find distance betwee two sequences invert one and find the longest common prefix.

def joinifmatch(seq1, seq2, minlen = 4):
    tail = seq2[:4]
    for i in range(len(seq1), 4, -1)
         if seq1.startswith(seq2[n-i:])
             return "%s%S"(seq2[:n-i], seq1)